# Is Gaussian $(X_1, X_2)$ optimal for $h(a_1X_1+ a_2X_2+Z_1) - \mu \, h( b_1X_1+b_2X_2+ Z_2)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory

Let \begin{align}
W  &= h(X_1+Z_1) - \mu \,  h( X_2+ Z_2) \quad (1)
\end{align} 
where $h(\cdot)$ is the differential entropy function, $\mu\ge 1 $ is a scalar, and $Z_1$ and  $Z_2$ are independent  and have Gaussian distributions. If $X=[X_1 \;  X_2]^t$ is independent of $Z_1$ and  $Z_2$, we know that a Gaussian $X$ is an optimal solution  for
\begin{aligned}
%{\mathcal W_0} =\;
&\underset{p(x)}{\text{maximize}}
& &  W\\
& \text{subject to}
& & \operatorname{Cov}(X) \preceq  S
\end{aligned}
in which $S$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

My question is whether  from the above we can deduce that 
\begin{aligned}
%{\mathcal W_0} =\;
&\underset{p(x)}{\text{maximize}}
& &  W'  = h(a_1X_1+ a_2X_2+Z_1) - \mu h( b_1X_1+b_2X_2+ Z_2) \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \operatorname{Cov}(X)\preceq S
\end{aligned}
where $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$ are scalars, is also maximized by a Gaussian $X$? 
In other words, in (1), can we simply replace $X_1$ and $X_2$ by $a_1X_1+a_2X_2$ and $b_1X_1+b_2X_2$? I assume $a_1b_2-a_2b_1\neq 0.$